# Too many clicks jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

I have the code:

```
    $(".click1").click(function() {
  $('.input').attr('name', 'name1');
});
$(".click2").click(function() {
  $('.input').attr('name', 'name2');
});
$(".click3").click(function() {
  $('.input').attr('name', 'name3');
});
$(".click4").click(function() {
  $('.input').attr('name', 'name4');
});
$(".click5").click(function() {
  $('.input').attr('name', 'name5');
});
```

How else to write? How do I change it to a short version?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it ? ie what are you trying to achieve ? why are you changing the name of an `input` field ?

Comment: Post an HTML with `.click1`, `.click2` elements etc.

Comment: Are u devising a game?? click challenge?

Comment: @madhairsilence dont be offensive.

Comment: if 'click1' is a button/link, you can get all the button/links on the page, loop through them and implement a common logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html:

```
 <a class="clickable" href="..." rel="1">...</a>
    <a class="clickable" href="..." rel="2">...</a>
    ....
```

JS:

```
 $('.clickable').click(function(){
      var _id = $(this).attr('rel');
      $('.input').attr('name', 'name' + _id);
 });
```

Comment: +1.  Not sure why it was voted down, but this is the best answer by far.  It does what it is supposed to and also it is probably best practice in general.  Voted back up to compensate.

Comment: Yup, I put . before name of class for links. Do you see any more errors in code? i didnt test it at all, just wrote out from my head :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

This should help man `:)`

Explanation: take the last character from your class and wack it in.

**Code**

```
$(".click1,.click2,.click3").click(function() {

    var num = $(this).attr('class');
    //get the number at the end of the class of this particular div           
    var lastChar = num.substr(num.length - 1)

    $('.input').attr('name', 'name'+lastChar);
});

​
```

Comment: @icrew Hiya man `:)` how do you mean, by the way I am not a DV `:)` *this solution* uses the **pattern from* OPs code and takes number out of them, i.e. last char - and this will not change any of the OPs DOM code.

Comment: not worries about downvote. Its not generic because if you want one more link you have to change code also. My code works for any number of as :)

Comment: I won't vote down, because he didn't specify that it had to be generic, but this will only work with this particular case.

Comment: @icrew saweet! D'uh `:)` I would avoid changing the DOM man, that will change the OPs actual question. but yes adding `common class will resolve the issue if OP want `:)` A1l good!

Comment: Also, you are not taking into consideration that there may be more than one class.  Example:  `<input class="click3 ui-state-default">` would attempt to set input with name "namet".

Comment: @Neil yep if OP wants to change the DOM then it will be cool, he/she can also do something like this `:)` **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/rFT8j/ but good point, like i mentioned I usually avoid any DOM structure change until OP says so. **but** adding simple class and clickable event or rather id's for these click will be better. Hope OP will read our discussion `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".click1, .click2, .click3, .click4, .click5").click(function() {
  $('.input').attr('name', 'name' + this.className.slice(-1));
});
```

Or the fun way (**not recommended**) if you have an unlimited number (and for whatever reason, don't want to [add another class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247992/851498)):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(function(e) {
    var f = '$(".click' + e + '").click(function() {';
    f += '$(".input").attr("name", "name' + e + '");';
    f += '});';
    new Function(f).call();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this way!

have a common class for all the components say "clickable" And use a simple if condition

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){

  if this object has 'click1' class { // do something }
  if this object has 'click2' class { // do something }
  if this object has 'click3' class { // do something }

});
```

Comment: That's a little better, but I don't think behavior between click1 and click2 is different enough to merit the repetition of code, but if it did, it should be rewritten anyway.

Answer (score -2):

javascript provides an `eval()` function. This is untested, but it should be something like:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    eval("$(\".click" + i +
        "\").click(function() {$('.input').attr('name', 'name" +
        i + "'); });");
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but, eval is evil!  We can solve this without resorting to gotos and evals, right?

Comment: You made my day! Using eval for this... Using eval is not recommended at all. Using your approach, it would be better to do something like this: `for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
 (function(n) {
  $(".click" + n ).click(function() { $('.input').attr('name', 'name' + n); });
 })(n);
}` (hope I made no mistake with closure...)